# Korean manhwa about a guy who cannot fight, but ends up winning every fight he is in

Tags: storm-bringer

I read this Korean manhwa about 2 years ago. I am bad at names, which is why I don't remember the title of the book, nor the names of any of the characters. This is not a popular series, and may not even have an anime. The manhwa is complete.

It has street fights. There are no superpowers whatsoever, as they are all humans. It's all about a guy becoming the top fighter in the school completely by accident.

I believe it takes place at an all boys high school, but there is a girl whom everyone mistakes for a guy attending the school for some reason. There are technically no rules against girls going to that school, though.

The main character is a complete wuss, with brown hair. In the first fight (maybe, not too sure), he pretends to be tough, then a group of people try to beat him up. However, he accidentally beats them all up instead. After that fight, I think pretty much all fights from that point on are 1 on 1, as people try to take him down and fail by sheer bad luck.

Even with all the fights going on, the parents are never involved, though I believe the principle is, and he literally beats up any kids that get into fights.

There's also a less popular remake where he can fight, but he keeps losing to everyone he tries to fight with. Basically, a complete flip of the series.

Feel free to make pot shot guesses, I will look up all answers.

Comment: Really vague. Can you at least give a time frame or when you think you read it? Were the fights like super powered fights or street brawls? Any info would help.

Comment: street brawls..

Comment: :/ Idk the main character is a complete wuss, and wins fights on accident... the chick is precived as a guy to everyone including the main character until the very end, and she can also fight, she is not ugly either, its just she just didn't seem to belong.. main character has brown hair, chick has pink.. there are several other characters to fight.. I am scared to add more detail, as I may get it wrong thus ruin the search...

Comment: Angel densetsu <a>http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/AngelDensetsu</a> in the story he is really a complete wuss but always ends up winning in fights in just pure luck

Comment: Nope, it Is not sen ken way :(

Comment: @ijustwannaknow look for Angel Densetsu (manga) it totally conforms in your story, he also become the top fighter in the manga by accident.

Comment: sadly that's not the series... :( thx assh for trying...

Comment: wow that series is like Verrry SIMILIAR.. dang, but the animation style is off by a lot, and its just not it... its like someone else had the same idea/ similar idea. tho this does remind me that the character im thinking of (tho his face isn't like creepy) can pull off a rather intimidating look.

Comment: @ijustwannaknow look at my answer below, try Transfer student Storm Bringer, the girl there has pink hair.

Comment: the answer is:•Transfer student Storm bringer  Assh O. Le popped up with five answers, and this was the last one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The series is [Transfer Student Storm Bringer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=63461).

The girl in this series has pink hair, and the guy has brown hair.

---

Maybe you are looking for [**Angel Densetsu**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/AngelDensetsu).

In the manga, the main character becomes the top fighter of his school due to luck/accident. As a result, many people from other schools come to challenge him to test his abilities, but he wins by luck as always.

He is totally a complete wuss with no experience in fighting, and he is just ugly.

---

If the manga above is not what you are looking for, try taking a look at the manga listed below. They also have the same trait as *Angel Densetsu* where the protagonists are just wusses and win by luck.

- [Ocha ni Gosu](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=15446)
- [Gorio](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=665)
- [Legend of the Strongest Man, Kurosawa](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=22320)
- [Bari Haken](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=26484)
- [Transfer Student Storm Bringer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=63461) (The girl in this series has pink hair, and the guy has brown hair)

Answer (score 0):

The series I was looking for is [Transfer Student Storm Bringer](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=63461). This is the only Korean manhwa among the series listed in [the answer above](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/20347/1398).

> Ju Ingong (which literally translates to Main character) has been terrifying all his schoolmates in every school he has been so far. He has one extremely scary face type and whoever lays his eyes on him thinks he is a BAMF (bad ass). Although… is he really?

Comment: i already posted this in my answer, you can accept it and point in the comment that that is what you are looking :)

Comment: lol I thought it was an automated answer thing because of all the http txt crap

Comment: btw i strongly recommend that you read angel densetsu it has a great plot. and its funny.

Comment: ill put it in my "to read area" lol I am just glad to get the name down, Now the only thing I don't know what is called that bothers me is a game I played when I was really young that was like bomberman, but you had to destroy the entire island, except the spot you where standing with tactical bomb placements...

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for Ultimate Legend: Kang Hae Hyo. He did not become a top fighter by accident. He was technically a beast in fighting until he got hit by a bus or truck (i can't fully recall which one was it). His lost memory started to re-surface as the fighting went on.

This manhwa also ticks the box on the girl you are looking for since the story involves a chick that was mistaken for a guy. She also led a gang where her gang members took her for a guy but for unknown reason she left the gang and only saw them again when she enrolled on a same school his former gang members were schooling at.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the author of the question has confirmed that it is Transfer Student Storm Bringer. Please check the other answers first before answering.

Comment: sorry about that, i thought  it was the manhwa he/she was looking for as the story is wayy too similar.